# Matrix segmentation into files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, segment

I have a very large matrix (M X N). I want to divide matrix into 10 equal parts (almost) and save each of them into a separate file say A1.txt,  A2.txt, etc. or .mat format. How can I do this ?

Below is a code to divide a matrix into 10 equal parts and data_size is (M / 10).

```
for i=1:10
    if i==1
        data = DATA(1:data_size,:);
    elseif i==10
         data = DATA((i-1)*data_size+1:end,:);
    else
         data = DATA((i-1)*data_size+1: i*data_size,:);
    end

    save data(i).mat data  
    % What should I write here in order to save data into separate file data1.mat, data2.mat etc. 

end
```

Comment: use `sprintf` to generate your file name. Then use `save(filename,'data');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
save(['data' num2str(i) '.mat'], 'data');
```

where `[ ]` is used to concatenate strings and `num2str` to convert an integer to a string.

Answer (score 3):

You said you wanted it in either `txt` format or `mat` format.  I'll provide both solutions, and some of this is attributed to [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2732801/daniel) in his comment in your post above.

---

## Saving as a text file

You can use [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) to open a file up for writing.  This returns an ID to the file that you want to write to.  After this, use [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html) and specify the ID to the file that you want to write to, and the data you want to write to this file.  As such, with `sprintf`, generate the text file name you want, then use `fprintf` to write data to your file.  It should be noted that writing matrices to `fprintf` in MATLAB assume **column major** format.  If you don't want your data written this way and want it done in row-major, you need to **transpose** your data before you write this to file.  I'll provide both methods in the code depending on what you want.

After you're done, use [`fclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html) to close the file noting that you have finished writing to it.  Therefore, you would do this:

```
for i=1:10
    if i==1
        data = DATA(1:data_size,:);
    elseif i==10
         data = DATA((i-1)*data_size+1:end,:);
    else
         data = DATA((i-1)*data_size+1: i*data_size,:);
    end

    filename = sprintf('A%d.txt', i); %// Generate file name
    fid = fopen(filename, 'w'); % // Open file for writing
    fwrite(fid, '%f ', data.'); %// Write to file - Transpose for row major!
    %// fwrite(fid, '%f ', data); %// Write to file - Column major!
    fclose(fid); %// Close file
end
```

Take note that I space separated the numbers so you can open up the file and see how these values are written accordingly.  I've also used the default precision and formatting by just using `%f`.  You can play around with this by looking at the `fprintf` documentation and customizing the precision and leading zero formatting to your desire.

---

## Saving to a MAT file

This is actually a more simpler approach.  You would still use `sprintf` to save your data, then use the [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) command to save your workspace variables to file.  Therefore, your loop would be this:

```
for i=1:10
    if i==1
        data = DATA(1:data_size,:);
    elseif i==10
         data = DATA((i-1)*data_size+1:end,:);
    else
         data = DATA((i-1)*data_size+1: i*data_size,:);
    end

    filename = sprintf('A%d.mat', i); %// Generate file name
    save(filename, 'data');
end
```

Take note that the variable you want to save must be a **string**.  This is why you have to put single quotes around the `data` variable as this is the variable you are writing to file.

Comment: 2nd approach has following error-           `Error using save
Argument must contain a string.

Error in XXXXXX
    save(filename, data);`

Comment: @user2771151 - My apologies.  Let me fix that for you.  I forgot to encapsulate the second argument in quotations